# CSS3 animation for flipcard not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

Making a flipcard for my personal website to flip between two photos on hover. Works fine in Chrome but not in Safari despite having all vendor prefixes in place. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<center><div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
<div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
        <img src="http://i1299.photobucket.com/albums/ag62/Liz_Reddinger/name%20title4_zpslapxhev7.png" width="220px" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <img src="http://i1299.photobucket.com/albums/ag62/Liz_Reddinger/unnamed_zpsbjazifcu.png" width="170px" draggable="false">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```html
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    margin-top:-300px;
}
.flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}
.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 1.2s;
    -moz-transition: 1.2s;
    transition: 1.2s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}
.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    margin-top:5px;
}
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

It seems like such a simple problem, but I'm plain stuck. I've seen on another few posts to be meticulous about defining percentages, but I haven't got to use them here.